# Inner join 2 tables one to many 2 where clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have 2 tables:

- OrderDetail
- OrderMaster

Both have a column named SalesOrder.

OrderDetail table has multiple rows per unique SalesOrder.
OrderMaster table has one row per unique SalesOrder.

OrderDetail has a column named LineType.
OrderMaster has a column named OrderStatus.

I want to select all records from OrderDetail that have a LineType of "1" AND whose matching SalesOrder line in the OrderMaster table has a OrderStatus column value of "4".

In plain English, orders with a Status 4 are open and ready to ship, LineType value of 1 means the Detail Line is a product code.

How should this query be structured?  It's going into VS 2008 (VB).

Comment: Pretty basic...give writing a query a try before asking for help

Comment: Please search for 'Inner Join Example' you will find plenty.

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't just do your work for you.  Show us what you have tried and explain exactly what you are having trouble with.

Comment: I see you are using SQL Server. Try creating a VIEW and see what it does. Pretty easy way to learn SQL visually.

Answer (score 2):

I can give you some sql:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM OrderDetails d
INNER JOIN OrderMaster m ON m.SalesOrder = d.SalesOrder
WHERE d.LineType = 1 and m.OrderType = 4
```

How you'll use that from VB.Net depends on a number of things that weren't included with your question.